# Не удается получить доступ к MSSQL в Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Установил образ SQL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В SSMS список локальных серверов пуст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке присоединиться по названиям SQL Server, SQLCONNECT и localhost вылетает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как соединиться с локальным сервером?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Нужно разрешить использовать Named Pipes](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-named-pipe-and-tcpip-settings-of-sql-server/)